# Ignore src and node modules in Google cloud build

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I had deployed a React app to google cloud Build. Deployment is successful. But I have to hide the src and node modules directory.

Currentely Its showing [image]

I have tried adding .gcloudignore with content

```
node_modules/
  *~
```

Do you have any idea how i can hide my source files. After the build all complied code generates in the dist directory.

Comment: Is this a `git` repository?

Comment: Yes its a git repo and currentely code deploy automatically on new commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the folders `node_modules` and `src` are in the top-level directory to be uploaded, then the `.gcloudignore` file will look like:

```
#!include:.gitignore
/node_modules/
/src/
*~
```

The first line `#!include:.gitignore` allows `.gitignore` file, 2nd, 3rd and 4th line prevents uploading of `node_modules`, `src` directory and any files ending in `~`.

Comment: Do you know how to see node logs in google app engine like i want to see the npm start commands logs etc etc

Comment: After adding 
#!include:.gitignore
/node_modules/
/src/
*~
It's showing

Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Then remove the first line from the file, and make sure there are no extra spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: the first line ignores all the files that `.gitignore` specifies.  Wether you include that line or not, the file `.gitignore` will be included like all other files not mentioned explicitly. You can test your exclusions with `gcloud meta list-files-for-upload`